# Why is first value of an C array and last value reversed without intention?

Tags: c

Here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 10000

int main(){
    int a[MAX], b[MAX], n;  
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int c, d, e, f;
        scanf("%d%d%d%d", &c, &d, &e, &f);
        if(f==e){
            a[c]+=1;
            a[d]+=1;
        }
        else{
            if(f>e){
                a[c]+=3;
            }
            else{
                a[d]+=3;
            }
        }
    }   
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

And here is it's input:

```
4 
1 2 0 0
3 4 1 0
1 3 2 1
2 4 1 1
```

There are 4 games, each game has 2 teams. The c and d are input variables could be changed in each input statement of the for loop, they help the program to indentify what team is it to add 1 point if c and d of that match are tie (that for loop), if c or d wins, gets 3 points and 0 point for loser. To know if c or d wins, e and f are the games scores and also can be changed in each input statement of the for loop.
For example:

- There are 4 games (given input):
- The first game ended up with 0-0 for team 1 and team 2(c and d now are 1 and 2, e and f are 0 and 0), by logically a[1] and a[2] values are 1 and 1 because they tie.
- Respective with the other games.
  In total, a[1]=4, a[2]=2, a[3]=3, a[4]=1. Then the expected array output must be: 4 2 3 1 but by somehow, my prgoram reversed the first and last value which is 1 2 3 4.

Comment: To begin with neither `a[]` nor `b[]` have been initialised to any particular value... Adding to their elements will give unpredictable results. Second look... What's the purpose of `b[]`?

Comment: Have you considered reversing the `if()` comparison? It looks like you award 3 points to the losing team instead of the winning team... If you test with data that shows a particular, easy to spot result, you'll be able to debug the code... Try it with only one game with a definite winner, then two games with the same team winning. Mixing up your test data merely makes it difficult to discern the code's behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check the return value from `scanf()` otherwise you may be operating on uninitialized values.
2. Initialize the array `a`.
3. There appears to be a logic error.  If `e < f` then we want to award points to `a[d]`.
4. The first index of arrays is 0 but your teams are between 1 and 4 so the output loop is wrong.  `c` and `d` are really labels so maybe write a function to extract an array of labels and iterative over those instead.
5. (not fixed) Consider using a "team, score" format instead of a flat list of 4 numbers.
6. The array `b` is not used.
7. (not fixed) The non-descriptive variables `a`, `c`, `d`, `e` and `f` makes your code hard to read.  For the last 4 what about `home`, `guest`, `home_score`, `guest_score`?
8. (not fixed) You should check that c and d are >= 0 and < MAX, otherwise you will have a buffer overflow.  Consider using unsigned values instead of (signed) int.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10000

int main() {
    int n;
    if(scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
        return 1;
    int a[MAX] = { 0 };
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        int c, d, e, f;
        if(scanf("%d%d%d%d", &c, &d, &e, &f) != 4)
            return 1;
        if(e < f)
            a[d] += 3;
        else if(f == e) {
            a[c]++;
            a[d]++;
        } else
            a[c] += 3;
    }
    for(int i=1; i<=4 ;i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

and example session:

```
4 
1 2 0 0
3 4 1 0
1 3 2 1 
2 4 1 1
4 2 3 1
```

Comment: what is if scanf statement used for ?

Comment: @HùngCường scanf() returns the number of elements read (or EOF).  If you don't check it you don't know if scanf() succeeded or not.